# In Spring Boot 3 how to benefit from Spring AOT with a regular JVM application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ahead-of-time-compile

Spring Boot 3 will release in November 2022. [The release candidate 2 has already been released.](https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/10/spring-boot-3-0-0-rc2-available-now)

[Spring Boot 3 will ship with Spring AOT.](https://spring.io/blog/2022/03/22/initial-aot-support-in-spring-framework-6-0-0-m3) Spring AOT generates additional source code so that reflection calls will be avoided.

Spring AOT was introduced to generate [GraalVM Native Images](https://www.graalvm.org/22.3/reference-manual/native-image/). However, in theory Spring AOT could also be used for regular JVM applications to speed up the start-up process (since regular calls should be faster than reflection calls).

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything about how to use Spring AOT for regular JVM applications in the [Spring Boot 3 reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-RC2/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.introducing-graalvm-native-images.understanding-aot-processing). Do you know how I can profit from Spring AOT in a regular JVM application?

Answer (score 3):

This document descibes [how to run AOT code on the JRE](https://github.com/spring-tips/spring-boot-3-aot#run-the-aot-code-on-the-jre).

Essentially, you have to build your jar like this

`mvn clean compile spring-boot:process-aot package`

and run it like this

`java -DspringAot=true -jar your-application.jar`

Comment: That's a little out of date. The property is now `-Dspring.aot.enabled=true`. For Gradle you need to apply the `org.springframework.boot.aot` plugin and configure your bundling task(s) to get the generated classes and properties into the jar by using `from sourceSets.aot.runtimeClasspath`

Answer (score -1):

I think they have gone in a different direction because of [this video from Spring advocate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUm5WZjh8RA&t=1210s). Looks like AOT is only being used with GraalVM only.

To answer your question, you can only use AOT benefits with GraalVM.

Comment: You can use AOT on the JVM, they imply this in the docs but it's not entirely clear. The AOT support and plugin is separate from Native Image.

Answer (score -1):

Two useful ways you can use AOT with Spring Boot:

### **Using a docker image**

Besides of having Java >= 17 and Gradle >= 7.3 installed, in your build.gradle you will add the following plugin:

```
id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.23'
```

An initial build.gradle would look like this:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.23'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

That's it. Now you can build your docker image running the follwing command:

```
gradle bootBuildImage
```

Now you can run `docker images` to see the image you just created and running it:

```
docker run --rm <image_id>
```

### **Compiling it to run as a native app**

In this case, you should apply the same plugin shown in the example above. Besides, you will have to have GraalVM >= 17 and Gradle >= 7.3 installed. Then, you can run the follwoing command to build it:

```
gradle nativeCompile
```

and to run your application, you can just run:

```
/<app_name>/build/native/nativeCompile/<app_name>
```

And that'all. It's important to mention that some Spring features may not work properly due to Closed World assumption, which can make reflection harder to implement.